# Como saber que checkbox van marcado o no?

Tags: php, symfony2

Estoy creando un array de CheckBox dinamicamente para que el usuario los marque y luego actualizar su estado en la base de datos:

```
{% for c in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural  ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input name="data[add][row{{ c.id }}]" id="caserio{{ c.id }}" type="checkbox"
                               value=" {{ c.id }}">
                        <span class="label-text"><span class="icon-check"></span> </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ c.nombre }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

El problema me surge al momento de saber cuales no van marcados ya que al controlador llegan los input que se han marcado con estos no tego problema, pero si el usuario lo desmarcó no llega al controlador

Comment: ¿Necesitas saberlo **en el controlador**? Si es así entonces tendrás que buscar alguna forma de serializarlos todos, por ejemplo en un objeto, que te diga cuáles están marcados y cuáles no y mandar ese objeto cuando haces el submit. ¿Usas algún framework? Conviene que pongas la etiqueta por si algún experto en ese framework puede darte algunas ideas propias del mismo.

Comment: Eso estaba pensado enviar un array de datos para poder compararlo con el array de checkbox

Answer (score -1):

Despues de un rato he decido hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Cread dos array que contengas los checbox que el usuario vaya seleccionando o desmarcando
2. luegos esos array enviarlos por ajax a un controlador

```html
<script type="application/javascript">
    let marcados = [];
    let noMarcados = [];
    function agregar(item) {
        const indexMarcado = marcados.indexOf(item.value);
        const indexNoMarcado = noMarcados.indexOf(item.value);
        if (item.checked) {
            if (indexNoMarcado > -1) {
                noMarcados.splice(indexNoMarcado, 1)
            }
            marcados.push(item.value)
            console.log("marcado"+marcados);
        } else {
            if (indexMarcado > -1) {
                marcados.splice(indexMarcado, 1)
            }
            noMarcados.push(item.value)
            console.log("No marcado"+noMarcados);
        }
    }

    function enviar() {
        let idEstablecimiento = $('#idEstablecimiento').select2('val');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate("actualizar_caserio_establecimiento"),
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: {marcados_: marcados, noMarcados_: noMarcados, idEstablecimiento_: idEstablecimiento},
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.success) {
                    alertify.notify('Actualización se realizó con exito', 'success', 5, function () {
                        console.log('dismissed');
                    });
                    $("#buscar").trigger("click");
                } else {
                    alertify.notify('Problemas al actualizar los datos', 'warning', 5, function () {
                        console.log('dismissed');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input name="data[add][row{{ c.id }}]" id="micheck" type="checkbox"
                                               value="10" onclick="agregar(this)" {{ c.verified }}>
                                               <input name="data[add][row{{ c.id }}]" id="micheck" type="checkbox"
                                               value="20" onclick="agregar(this)" {{ c.verified }}>
```